# Laravel blade mixed relationships. How can I do that?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have a question. I have two tables:
*devices* and *persons*

In these DB one device can be assigned to one person (so it's one to one relationshiip), but one person may have many devices (so this is one to many relationship).How can I do that in Laravel? For one to one is little easy and in model I can do that:

**Devices**

```
class Devices extends Model
{
    public function persons(){

        return $this->hasOne('App\Persons','id');

    }
}
```

**Persons**

```
class Persons extends Model
{
    public function devices(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Devices');

    }
}
```

SO I think this is one to one relationship: one device assigned to one person.

How can I get many device to one person? Change belongsTo to belongsToMany in Persons model? Is these will be allright for those variations?

Comment: As a side note, you should name your models singularly (is that a word? ^^), because one instance represents one object, not multiple ones. `new Persons()` makes no sense, because it creates only one `Person`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [`one-to-many`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relation, so your relation will look as:

Persons

```
class Persons extends Model
{
    public function devices(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Devices');

    }
}
```

Devices

```
class Devices extends Model
{
    public function person(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Persons');

    }
}
```

Comment: You could add a link to the documentation of Laravel about relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: @AntoineB Was just adding that :P

Comment: Nope it's indeed correct, I don't know why you're getting downvoted. By the way, specifying `id` is not useful in the `Devices` model.

Comment: @AmitGupta, I do not know what happens, but lately I get many down-votes. I start to think that the community at SO is not as constructive as before and I start to wonder whether there is any point to contribute to it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**Persons**

```
public function devices() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Devices');
}
```

Means that Person will have many Devices.

**Devices**

```
public function persons() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Persons');
}
```

Means that Device belongs to some Person.

---

More information: http://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many